# How can I figureout what format or features of my regex code this firefox addon wants?

Tags: regex, json, firefox

I am trying to write plugins for the extension (Anticontainer) for the FireFox plugin (DownThemAll).

Plugins are .json files and they use regex.

Issues normally arise in my code in the "finder" region.
If there is an issue, I get no notification, it simply does not import.

For example,
This does import;

```
"finder": "<img src=\"(resized/([^\"]+))\"",
```

This does not import;

```
"finder": "src="(http://.*.cdn..*.com.*-\d+x\d+.jpg)"\Wclass="",
```

Both match correctly in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

It is almost always an issue with the finder region. I can take the finder region from a plugin that does import and put it in one that doesn't and it will import.

```
This is the error that firefox gives me
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIJSON.decodeFromStream]" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: resource://dtaac/plugins.jsm :: loadPluginFromStream :: line 211" data: no]
```

It points to this file; https://github.com/downthemall/anticontainer/blob/master/modules/plugins.jsm

Simply, I can not figure what FireFox, DownThemAll, Anticontainer, JSON files and/or JSM files require in their RegEx.

Can anybody direct me to a method of determining what this damn thing doesn't like about some of my regexp code.

I have gotten it to work. I fixed a facebook album downloader plugin, but it's taking way to long to constantly rewrite the regex and import till it accepts it.

Suggestions on how to figure out what can and can not be in my regexp and what this extension requires from the regexp to import.

Comment: I think the syntax highlighter on SO should be giving you a very strong hint right now (stronger hint: escape your quotes).

Comment: @Chris is right.  I was about to disable the syntax highlighting when I realized it was answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your problem is not with regex syntax but with string-literal syntax.  This:

```
src="(http://.*.cdn..*.com.*-\d+x\d+.jpg)"\Wclass="
```

...is a valid regex, but when you put it in a string literal, you have to escape the quotes:

```
"src=\"(http://.*.cdn..*.com.*-\d+x\d+.jpg)\"\Wclass=\""
```

...and according to [this reference](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EscapingExamples), you need to escape the other backslashes and the forward-slashes as well:

```
"src=\"(http:\/\/.*.cdn..*.com.*-\\d+x\\d+.jpg)\"\\Wclass=\""
```

Finally, if the `\W` near the end is meant to match a space, you should use `\s` instead.  Many people assume `\W` means whitespace, but it's really equivalent to `[^\w]`: any character that's not a word character.  It's not strictly an error to use `\W` in this case, but I wanted to make sure you knew the difference.